# Laravel: Cannot retrieve an relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

It seems like Laravel 4 cannot get an relation when I use the ::where() syntax. So this is what I have:

```
<?php
  // works fine
  $questions = Auth::user()->questions;

  // error
  $questions = User::where('profilename', '=', $username)->questions;

  // error
  $questions = User::where('profilename', '=', $username)->get()->questions;
?>
```

The first method just works fine, but the second an third not.

These give the following error:
"Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$questions "

Any idea on how I can make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$questions = User::where('profilename', '=', $username)->first()->questions;
```

Relationships only works from a model and not an array of models which you have when you use get()